# Selecting from two different MYSQL databases

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch data from these two different databases and pass the details into the url. The values in company database and table safdetail are updated often however, the details in workers database  do not change. I can not think of a way to pass the two together efficiently. Anyone?

```
//Connect to company database
 $sql = "SELECT mobilenumber, amount FROM safdetail WHERE notification = 0";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); // fetch data



     $mobile = $resultarr['mobilenumber'];
     $amount = $resultarr['amount'];


 //connect to workers database
  $sq = "SELECT shortCode, spId, password, commandID, serviceID  FROM workers WHERE notification = 0";

 $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sq);
 $resultarr1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data

    $shortCode = $resultarr1['shortCode'];
    $spId = $resultarr1['spId'];
    $password = $resultarr1['password'];
    $commandID = $resultarr1['commandID']; 
    $serviceID = $resultarr1['shortCode'];  



                 $serviceArguments = array(
                            "serviceID" => $serviceID,
                            "shortCode" => $shortCode,
                            "spId" => $spId,
                            "password" => $password,
                            "mobilenumber" => $mobile,
                            "amount" => $amount,
                            "commandID" => $commandID
                            );

            $client = new SoapClient("http://32.37.12.12:8080/B2DSimulator/Simulator?wsdl");

            $result = $client->process($serviceArguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access tables accross different databases just prefix the database before the tablename like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.myTable1 AS db1, DB2.myTable2 AS db2
```

If you need a more specific answer to your mentioned code, please let me know and I will dig a bit more into your specific problem.

Edit: After reading your code I think that this is already the fastest way to accomplish your goals. For your specific case you may want to use memcached to cache your workers table for a longer time. You should also make sure that you index the notification field on both tables as you use this for your query. This will improve your query speed on big tables a lot.

Depending on how large your table is and how long the queries take there are also other possible improvements. If you use InnoDB you may want to take a look into using transactions. I don't know how long these queries take or what exactly the performance issue is (is this php file called very often and you want to avoid to execute these queries again and again or do these queries take to long until there is a result?)

**Side note:** You may want to redact the IP and URL in your code.

Comment: Hello there. so for my case should I do this `SELECT * FROM company.safdetail AS db1, workers.workers AS db2`  From there I need more especially considering my specific question. Kindly... **For the URL and IP** I have already redacted thank you.

Comment: @Bob I edited my answer, please elloborate what exactly is not performant enough or what exactly you want to improve. How often is this file called per second/minute, how long does it take until there is a result from both queries?

Comment: The php script is not called often but when called, the company database could have a lot of records but the workers database has a static record that is fetched every time to accompany the rest records from the other db. I was not sure if this would work efficiently if for instance lot of records are entered at once.

Comment: @Bob then my edited answer contains the way to go. If you use InnoDB with a proper Buffer poolsize the table engine will handle it automatically for you, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html . You can read about the advantages of using memcached here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-benefits.html